# Could not find 'androidx.support:support-v4:+' Can anyone help me out?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx

While **building my project**, I get this error :-

> Could not find androidx.support:support-v4:+ ______ Required by:
> project :app

I don't know why I get this error, even I have added the dependency...

My **build.gradle(:app)** :-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.android.application'
    // Other plugins here if pre-existing
}

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true}
    compileSdk 32

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dccodes.chugli"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.0'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.dccodes.chugli'
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.support:support-v4:'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.pgreze:android-reactions:1.6'
    implementation 'com.devlomi:circularstatusview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.OMARIHAMZA:StoryView:1.0.2-alpha'
    implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.8.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.24'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My **build.gradle(Chugli)** :-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know why I get this error, I have even **cleaned my project** several time...

**Can anyone help me out ?**

Comment: Afaik, there is no `androidx` package for `support-v4`, so simply remove `implementation 'androidx.support:support-v4:'` from your dependencies.

Comment: Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: After trying that, I get this error :-
```The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.```

Comment: You need to migrate your project & other libraries to AndroidX. Seems either your project or a library is still using legacy support libraries which won't work.

Comment: How to migrate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247874/discussion-between-king-and-darshan).

Answer (score -1):

You are not providing the version in the dependency. Try to add the version and then rebuild it.

Comment: It is not working, I have tried by adding and removing the version but I get the same error...

Comment: There is no `androidx.support:support-v4` package. Please check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages

Comment: You can add android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true in the gradle.properties

Comment: I have alredy used it....